# Dialog box in C++ not receiving certain keystrokes

Tags: c++, windows, dialog

As I'm (finally) learning to code Windows apps in C++ I stumbled upon this: I have a dialog box which I create with `CreateDialog()` and I also have a default button. However, each time I press `TAB` or `ENTER`, nothing happens, nor does the control focus change, nor does the default button activate. Here's the resource for my dialog.

```
IDD_MAINWIND DIALOG 0, 0, 312, 205
STYLE DS_CENTER | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_SHELLFONT | WS_CAPTION | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU
EXSTYLE WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "Tahoma"
{
    PUSHBUTTON      "&Send", IDC_BUTTON_SEND , 280, 168, 22, 14, BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON
    LTEXT           "Hello", IDC_STATIC1, 9, 9, 296, 149, SS_LEFT | SS_NOPREFIX | SS_SUNKEN, WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
    EDITTEXT        IDC_MESSAGE, 9, 168, 265, 13, ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    PUSHBUTTON      "Tools", IDC_BUTTON_TOOLS, 8, 185, 146, 14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Exit", IDC_BUTTON_EXIT, 163, 185, 136, 14
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Especially now on the 3rd day of Christmas.

Comment: Any resource editor will take care of this for you. Which one are you using?

Comment: What a shame. I'm writing it by myself, in the hope that I'll learn this. I'm using Code::Blocks and I'm having a pretty hard time working... but at least it works.

Comment: Fair enough. It's not *difficult* to do this by hand, just tedious. The style flags (like the one you need, `WS_TABSTOP`) don't have any direct relationship with resource scripts. They're the standard window styles that you set for all windows/controls, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx). When you grow sufficiently comfortable with your own skills (or tired of practicing), download [ResEdit](http://www.resedit.net/).

Comment: I've added `WS_TABSTOP` everywhere and it still does not work... :| I hear a beep each time I press enter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to add `WS_TABSTOP` styles to every child element of the dialog box.

For ex.:

```
PUSHBUTTON      "&Send", IDC_BUTTON_SEND , 280, 168, 22, 14, BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP
```

Be sure that every control has `WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD` styles.
Also do not forget to add `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` style to the window and remove `WS_GROUP` style from the dialog window.

**Moreover**

**Check your dialog proc**

**Or if you use window proc instead** use the following snippet

Tabbing is provided by the dialog manager, not the Window manager. Therefore, to get tab handling, you need to call `IsDialogMessage` in your message loop with the hwnd of your window:

```
/* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    if (!IsDialogMessage(hwnd, &messages))
    {
        /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }
}
```

Please, learn about WS_TABSTOP and WS_GROUP dialog box items attributes.

This link should be helpful for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644994.aspx#controls

Comment: This didn't really help me, the same thing happens. I should say that I hear a beep each time I press enter.

Comment: Then try to add `WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE` style to the controls.

Comment: Okay. Maybe you forgot to set initial focus? `SetFocus(GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, ID_BUTTON_SEND); `

Comment: Did this too. Now the button is selected, but I can only press it using spacebar, not enter. Tab is still ignored, I can't navigate through the controls using it. (Btw thank you for your help so far)

Comment: add `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` to the dialog style

Comment: send me the solution on n.loshchinin _at_ gmail.com

Comment: I think I know what is the problem. I've updated the answer. Do not forget to add styles I've told you to add