# Using Tab to move to another edit control in the main app window

Tags: c, windows, winapi, user-interface, win32gui

Hello I was reading through some other posts about my issue on SO that haven't been quite answered yet (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644543/dialog-box-in-c-not-receiving-certain-keystrokes)). I have the same problem about now. I have ***a main window*** on C/Win32 with many edit controls in the form below. Note that those buttons only work on my Main app window...

```
hEdit = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT", "1",
            WS_GROUP | WS_VISIBLE | ES_NUMBER | ES_RIGHT,
            180, 94, 28, 20, hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_ATTRIBUTE_FITNESS, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
```

and I would like to move from one to another using the tab key. As you can imagine I can't and I have tried whatever I could.
I have tried using any combination **WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE** and **WS_GROUP** but nothing worked. Every time I press Tab key while in one of my edit controls I hear the 'beep' tone from Windows. Anyone can provide insightful information about that or maybe a little tutorial or demonstration online to get hold of it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your controls the `WS_TABSTOP` style and then use `IsDialogMessage` in your message loop.  Also see Raymond Chen's "[Using the TAB key to navigate in non-dialogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/21/55384.aspx)" article for some more details and for sample code.

Comment: Oh yea I was just using if (IsDialogMessage(hwnd, &Msg)) and then Translate(Msg) etc instead putting that code inside the else. Thank you very much.

Comment: You may also need to specify the extended style WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT as shown here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/09/30/10069580.aspx